# Restar datos entre tablas si coincide X elemento

Tags: c#, datatables, sql

La explicacion es un poco larga pero quiero hacerme entender con el problema lo mas detallado posible.
Tengo 4 tablas, 2 indican la informacion de material usado y material devuelto (`Transacciones` y `Devoluciones`) y las otras 2 tablan detallan que material se uso o se devolvio (`Trans_det1` y `Devol_det1`)

Cada material que se utiliza o no viene detallado por boletas, que estan vienen detallas por ordenes de trabajo, un ejemplo:

Tengo las siguientes sentencias:

```
--REGISTRO DE INGRESO
SELECT*FROM Transa WHERE orden='GORE-999888'

--REGISTRO DE DEVOLUCIONES
SELECT*FROM Devol WHERE orden='GORE-999888'
```

Me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla `Transa`me devuelve todas las boletas que se usaron para esa orden y `Devol` tambien pero me muestra las boletas que se usaron para devolver material.

**DETALLES DE MATERIALES**

```
--LO QUE SE USO
SELECT Transa_det1.boleta, Transa_det1.rollo, Transa_det1.cantidad FROM Transa_det1,Transa 
WHERE Transa.boleta=Transa_det1.boleta AND orden='GORE-999888'

--LO QUE SE DEVOLVIO
SELECT Devol_det1.boleta, Devol_det1.rollo, Devol_det1.cantidad FROM Devol_det1, Devol
WHERE Devol_det1.boleta=Devol.boleta AND orden='GORE-999888'
```

Me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui me devuelve los rollos que se usaron en las boletas de la orden XXXX y cuanto se uso, la segunda tabla me muestra la cantidad de rollos que se devolvio.

Viene mi pregunta, para el rollo `RT0102`estoy usando `100.5`pero despues devolvi `100`al final lo que realmente use fueron `0.5`, igual para `RT0103` use `250` pero despues devolvi `50`, existe una forma de hacer la resta si rollos coinciden mientras sean de la misma orden todo en un solo `query`? osea que me devuelva de una vez:

```
RT0103 0.5
RT0102 200
FH0091 465.75 //ESTE QUEDA IGUAL PORQUE NO DEVOLVI MATERIAL DE ESTE
```

(Otra opcion que estoy pensando es recuperar cada tabla en un DataTable C# y despues realizar algun tipo de resta para colocar el resultado en una nueva Datatable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final me sirvio este codigo:

```
SELECT td.boleta, 
       td.rollo, 
       ( td.cantidad - Isnull(c.ret, 0) ) AS Total 
FROM   transa_det1 td
       INNER JOIN transa ta
               ON ta.boleta = td.boleta 
       OUTER apply (SELECT top 1 d1.cantidad AS Ret 
                    FROM   devol_det1 d1
                           INNER JOIN devol d
                                   ON d1.boleta = d.boleta 
                    WHERE  d1.rollo = td.rollo and d.orden=ta.orden)c 
where ta.orden = 'GORE-999888' //el orden puede cambiar
```

Que me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
with Usado as (
    SELECT Transa_det1.boleta, Transa_det1.rollo, Transa_det1.cantidad 
    FROM Transa_det1,Transa 
    WHERE Transa.boleta=Transa_det1.boleta AND orden='GORE-999888'
),
Devuelto as (
    SELECT Devol_det1.boleta, Devol_det1.rollo, Devol_det1.cantidad 
    FROM Devol_det1, Devol
    WHERE Devol_det1.boleta=Devol.boleta AND orden='GORE-999888'
)
select U.boleta, U.rollo, U.cantidad - D.cantidad as Cantidad 
from Usado U
left join Devuelto D
    on U.rollo = D.Rollo
```

Comment: da cantidad nula si lo intento