# Usar INNER JOIN multiples tablas

Tags: sql, linq

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
 SELECT td.boleta, 
       td.rollo, 
       ( td.cantidad - Isnull(c.ret, 0) ) AS Total 
FROM   transa_det1 td
       INNER JOIN transa ta
               ON ta.boleta = td.boleta 
       OUTER apply (SELECT top 1 d1.cantidad AS Ret 
                    FROM   devol_det1 d1
                           INNER JOIN devol d
                                   ON d1.boleta = d.boleta 
                    WHERE  d1.rollo = td.rollo and d.orden=ta.orden)c 
where ta.orden = 'GORE-999888'//ORDEN PUEDE CAMBIAR, ESTE ES EJEMPLO
```

Me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es saber como puedo modificar este `query`que al momento de escoger el `rollo` este vaya a la tabla `Casiller`y me obtenga que `cod_parte` le corresponde al `rollo`y despues con ese `cod_parte` obtener la `descripcion`de ese rollo.

Por ejemplo: en la tabla `Casiller`tengo que el `rollo`  `RT0102` y `RT0103` tienen el mismo `cod_parte`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya con el `cod_parte`encontrado irme a la tabla `Partes` y encontra su `descripcion`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al final lo que quiero es ver como hacer para que el `query`me devuelve los datos asi:

```
boleta-----cod_parte----rollo-----descripcion-----------total
99998888   111555       RT0102    ROLLO REQUE PRUEBA    0.5
44445555   111555       RT0102    ROLLO REQUE PRUEBA    200
```

Comment: ¿existe alguna tercer tabla?

Comment: De dónde sacarías Descripcion y Total? Supongo que por eso la pregunta en el comentario anterior...

Comment: @FranciscoJavierGarduño son 4 tablas mas, que vienen de esta pregunta que hice: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239347/restar-datos-entre-tablas-si-coincide-x-elemento, como ya complete eso, ahora quiero agregar mas infor

Comment: @antonio_veneroso `descripcion` viene de la tabla `Partes` y `Total` viene del `query` (edite la sentencia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT td.boleta, 
   ca.cod_parte,  /* <-- agregado */
   td.rollo, 
   p.descripcion, /* <-- agregado */
   ( td.cantidad - Isnull(c.ret, 0) ) AS Total 
FROM   transa_det1 td
   INNER JOIN transa ta
           ON ta.boleta = td.boleta
/* agregado */
    INNER JOIN Casiller ca ON ca.rollo = td.rollo
    INNER JOIN Partes   p  ON p.cod_parte = ca.cod_parte
/* fin agregado */
    ... el resto de tu query ...
```